Run only a single chunk's worth of data without creating a Dask graph of all my chunks?
# Template xarray based on Earth Engine
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask
import xarray as xr

# Define the dimensions
time = pd.date_range("2020-12-29T18:57:32.281000", periods=3)
X = np.linspace(-421600, 486700, 9084)
Y = np.linspace(-599200, 458500, 10578)

# Create a data array with random data for each variable
data = np.random.rand(len(time), len(X), len(Y)).astype(np.float32)

# Create a dictionary of data variables
data_vars = {
    'SR_B4': (['time', 'X', 'Y'], data),
    'SR_B5': (['time', 'X', 'Y'], data)
}

chunk_size = {'time': 3, 'X': 1, 'Y': 1}

# Create the dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=data_vars,
    coords={'time': time, 'X': X, 'Y': Y},
    attrs={
        'date_range': '[1365638400000, 1654560000000]',
        'description': '<p>This dataset contains atmospherically corrected data.</p>',
        'keywords': ['cfmask', 'cloud', 'fmask', 'global', 'l8sr', 'landsat'],
        'period': 0,
        'visualization_2_max': 30000.0,
        'visualization_2_min': 0.0,
        'visualization_2_name': 'Shortwave Infrared (753)',
        'crs': 'EPSG:3310'
    }
).chunk(chunk_size)

I want to be able to grab only a single chunk's worth of data and run it through Dask. However, I don't want Dask to lazily queue up tasks for each chunk as I have selected a very small chunk size. I simply want to run a single chunk of a specific size without doing a full computation on the entire dataset. In other words, I'd like Dask to create a task graph consisting of just one chunk. I could create a dataset that matches the size of my chunk, but I'd like to see if there is another option. I acknowledge this is against Dask's documentation on determining optimal chunk sizes.

The way you built the dataset through Numpy and rechunk afterwards make this impossible. Data should be initialized already chunked, and then this would be possible.
